# Result and IQArray could not be found

Tags: programming, q#

I am following [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/quantum/user-guide/host-programs?tabs=tabid-csharp) MS tutorial to add functionality to my Q#/C#host project.

However, I get two errors on my operations:

```
The type or namespace name 'Result' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [host]csharp(CS0246)

The type or namespace name 'IQArray<>' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [host]csharp(CS0246)
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these two types come from `Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core` namespace, so if you add `using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core;` to the directives in the C# code, it should work.

Comment: Spot on! Adding `using Microsoft.Quantum.Simulation.Core` to my host `Program.cs` directives fixed it. Many thanks ツ

Comment: Thank you for bringing this up! I'm following up internally to have this fixed in the documentation